# Counting specific conditions in 2 different vectors in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to count the specific conditions in 2 vectors in R. I have two large vectors called pvals and slopes. They contain slopes and p-values of data. Below are the first 100 values of these vectors:

`> head(pvals,100)`

```
  [1] 0.0286411559 0.0286411559 0.0060436606 0.0044184582 0.0202363785 0.0227271128 0.0007566564
  [8] 0.0271831731 0.0023011522 0.0206544551 0.0007249833 0.7183587408 0.5803456268 0.0152314273
  [15] 0.1718698129 0.0128044906 0.0757572219 0.0009760651 0.0470163838 0.1517369626 0.0024644945
  [22] 0.0493502827 0.5658583570 0.6658280009 0.9146215594 0.3887724597 0.1036408181 0.5696856797
  [29] 0.0755709818 0.0209920775 0.0429251041 0.0282958818 0.0005714054 0.0548373388 0.1500129561
  [36] 0.1500129561 0.0121617952 0.6015826827 0.0644547917 0.0503562524 0.0359662491 0.1992504564
  [43] 0.1068490792 0.3032918301 0.2740815955 0.1116532948 0.4112584264 0.1123592102 0.0223919748
  [50] 0.0154503364 0.0085445602 0.8011353582 0.0283239175 0.0708823081 0.0278879937 0.0366787895
  [57] 0.0366787895 0.0406716656 0.4466742038 0.3172593264 0.0316967721 0.5941518114 0.4192583861
  [64] 0.7213843139 0.5898476729 0.2395406521 0.4084365066 0.1755794718 0.1246763527 0.9159482043
  [71] 0.6483876524 0.3196620709 0.7292097707 0.8643754317 0.3387484656 0.0601815599 0.0601815599
  [78] 0.9551529183 0.0269084278 0.0025313742 0.0817620408 0.1200289419 0.0024950085 0.0032553292
  [85] 0.4467557263 0.2183478291 0.2503150829 0.0791877450 0.0537520356 0.9982238948 0.2133573082
  [92] 0.0107443269 0.3159026134 0.0519112173 0.0981810181 0.0870442070 0.0870442070 0.6522994702
  [99] 0.1166907645 0.9762800193
```

`> head(slopes,100)`

```
  [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1
  [32]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  [63] -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1
  [94]  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1
```

How can I count the number of values that have a p-value > 0.01? The number of values that have a p-value < 0.01 but a slope of 1? The number of values that have a p-value < 0.01 but a slope of -1? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can use a logical condition with `pvals` and use `sum` to count the number of cases

```
sum(pval > 0.01)
```

Or if we are interested in the 'slopes', then use the logical condition to subset the 'slopes' and get the `sum`

```
sum(slopes[pval > 0.01])
```

Or if we need the count of pvalue < 0.01 and slope of 1

```
sum(slopes == 1 & pval < 0.01)
```

Assuming that both vectors are of the same `length`